# Passing parameter to get member through simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, form-for, simple-form-for

I'm trying to implement a search function but can't figure out what `simple_form_for` needs to match up with the routes:

```
resources :shows do
  member do
    get :search
  end

  resources :episodes
end
```

I've tried a few different formats:

```
# views/shows/_search.html.erb

<%= simple_form_for :search, url: search_show_path(show), :method => :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :search %>

  <%= f.button :submit, "Search", class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>

<%= simple_form_for search_show_path(show), :method => :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :search %>

  <%= f.button :submit, "Search", class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>

<%= simple_form_for search_show_url(show), :method => :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :search %>

  <%= f.button :submit, "Search", class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

When I place a string in the controller in place of `params[:search]` the query works, so I'll leave that code out. I'm calling the form with `<%= render 'search', show: @show %>` in `views/shows/show.html.erb`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are expecting an object in `params[:id]`, this means its a member route and not a collection one.

Change your routes file to:

```
resources :shows do
  member do
    get :search
  end

  resources :episodes
end
```

Debug Hint: Always see whats the URL that is getting built (e.g. http://localhost:3000/shows/search.6?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Bsearch%5D=test&commit=Search) in this case.. 6 was not getting passed in the URL correctly.. thus an issue with path helpers.